# How to make a div cover completely the top of the page?

Tags: css, html, background-color

How to make a div cover completely the top of the page? It seems like the higher position I can place a div isn't the absolute top of the page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuFEf.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for padding and margins on the html and body elements. Use the following CSS: `html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0;}` and see if that sorts it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `absolute` positioning, with 100% width and height, and use `z-index`. Set `top` and `left` to Zero. You can calculate width and height of page using javascript. 100% doesn't mean you give 100% in CSS, it means actual values of resolution.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

use this and you are done

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;width:100%;height:100%;margin:0px;padding:0px;z-index:9001;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure div has style `position:absolute; top:0;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using margins and / or paddings on the top of your page. You could place it absolute as mentioned by the two others, or you can place it relative and adjust the body tag. In this case you'd probably have to do something like this:

```
body
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for position absolute in this case. You will just break the flow.

I would suggest adding

```
body
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

as stated by a couple before me. That should be enough.